# Do old assets get deleted on iOS app update?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, asset-catalog

When a user updates an iOS app to its latest version, do the images used by that app's previous version/s (and no longer used by its latest version) get automatically deleted?

For example, let's say I add a custom PNG image (for a button in my app) to my app's asset catalog as explained by [Xcode Overview: Adding Images](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/AddingImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH50-SW1) and release version 1 of my app to the App Store. Then I rename the image and release version 2 of my app to the App Store. If a user who already has version 1 of my app installed on their device updates to version 2 of my app, will the image with the old name get deleted (since version 2 of my app no longer uses that image)?

I'm wondering because I want to minimize my app's use of device storage.

Comment: Yes. All the files in the app are replaced and nothing is left behind except files created by your app while using it.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen OK. Thank you. How do you know this?

Comment: How it will delete? if you are setting the image in IB it will not appear, but it will not be deleted.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2285/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011323 @ma11hew28 I think this one would clear things up.

Comment: `Xcode's app install process is optimized for development, but is slightly different than how iTunes and the App Store install apps. This is good during development because it's faster, but using Xcode to install an app over an older old build may create a "frankenbuild" with legacy files inside the .app bundle that won't exist after an App Store update.
When an app is updated, the old .app bundle is completely replaced, and all data in the old app container may be preserved as well.
`

Comment: OK. Thanks, all. @AjinkyaSharma, do you know what they mean by "app container"?

Comment: @ma11hew28 the app container is your sandbox container which contains things like your documents directory etc. That wont be replaced on an app update.