# how to manage changed flutter assets when updating app in ios app store

Tags: ios, flutter, deployment

I am making an iOS app that uses assets to store audio files. I setup TestFlight to do testing. I discovered I had a bad audio file, so replaced it and deployed a new build. The changed file did not show up after the update in TestFlight. This appears to be because assets are stored as user data and app updates preserve user data. I had to delete the app and reinstall it to get the changed asset to appear.

So I'm assuming any update to an app that modifies an existing asset must include code to detect the update and then overwrite the asset with a new version.
or else the asset must be renamed, though this will leave the original asset taking up memory. I have not been able to find any discussion on this topic.

Can an asset be overwritten? if so how?
Am I missing something here?

**Update:** I have submitted an issue on the GitHub flutter/flutter project

**Another Update:**
I was asked to present the problem with out third party packages. This led me to look deeper into just_audio which is what I am using. After eventually finding the place where assets are loaded, it turns out it defaults to always caching audio files in the app's temp directory which persists across app reloads and updates. You must make an explicit function call to clear the cache in the event of changed assets. It would have been nice if this was mentioned in the documentation.

Anyway, problem solved, and I feel kinda dumb for not suspecting just_audio was the source of the issue.

Comment: [There is already a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60312359/do-old-assets-get-deleted-on-ios-app-update) and what was discussed in the question this behavior is common for development, but it is different in the appstore.

Comment: Since I can not test the update process for the app store before my app is ready to distribute, I can only rely on TestFlight. TestFlight app updates should not require that the user first delete the app and then re-install it to get a valid working version of the app. It defaults to doing an update. This issue also happens locally using the simulator and connected devices. It should not be a required workflow to delete apps every time an asset is modified in order to test it. This is counter productive for development, not helpful.